# Difference between handling Application.ThreadException and wrapping Application.Run in Try / Catch

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

Is there any reason to prefer one of these methods of implementing a global exception handler in a Windows Forms application over the other?

**First Method**

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    try
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(mainform);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log error and display error message
    }
}
```

**Second Method**

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += 
        new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
    System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(mainform);
}

static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Log error and display error message
}
```

Does handling the ThreadException event give you something that the try / catch doesn't?

Comment: The First Method doesn't even work in Release mode, i.e. when you run your exe this will be an Unhandled exception, and you will NOT reach the catch block; only works while using visual studio. Try it, put a button inside your mainform and throw an exception there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My understanding of this behavior is that adding a [ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) handler will cause otherwise unhandled exceptions in forms to be caught and processed by this handler, which will allow the application to continue running.

In your try/catch design, the first unhandled exception in a form will cause the application to halt. You will catch the exception, but the application will then come to an end.

Note that there is also an [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) event that will be raised in certain cases (unhandled exceptions in threads other than the main windows forms thread and not catching the ThreadException), all of which are very bad news for your app.

Comment: Ah thanks, that's actually pretty obvious now that you point it out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The event handler approach allows your app to catch the exception, try to recover from it and continue. (i.e. execution does not leave `Application.Run`)

A `try/catch` in main will catch the exception but you will have left `Application.Run` at which point about all you can do is exit.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I would give you the check but the other answer had you beat by 8 seconds.